# Typescript: how to switch off ambient declarations when using AMD

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, amd

I'm just starting to migrate from internal modules to external modules in Typescript. Until now in my .d.ts files I have used the "declare var ..." part, because everything was used from the global namespace. But now with AMD I want my IDE to highlight errors if I use something without a corresponding import statement, so I do not want any ambiet declarations. How do I achieve that without modifying all my definition files manually (which would not work well with my tsd retrieval tool if I needed to do any updates)

Thanks!

Comment: Undecidable without seeing some real code. In some languages some IDE-s try very hard to be super magically helpful, for example JetBrains's code inspections for `php` language are simply awesome feature. Some their IDE claims to support `TypeScript` as well → maybe worth taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry : Can't be done without modifying the declaration files manually.